# "The drinking was according to doctrine, no forcing." -- Forcing to drink, or forcing to stop drinking?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, parshanut-torah-comment

The party is described at the beginning of the book of Esther as having drinking with "ein oness" -- "there was none forcing."

I'd always heard (assumed?) that meant no one would force you to drink any more than you wanted.

It appears [Rabbi David Fohrman's reading](http://www.forward.com/articles/135996/) is that no one would force you to *stop* ("cut you off", "code 86") drinking.

What do the commentaries say about this?

Answer (score 6):

Me'am Loez (citing [Yosef Lekach](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11721&pgnum=21)) says something similar, though not so much about the quantity of wine as of cups: there were enough to go around that no one was made to hurry up and finish drinking so that someone else could use the cup.

Answer (score 3):

*Rashi* says no one was made to drink more than he wanted.

The *g'mara* (12a) says everyone was given wine from his country, which *Rashi* there says was so he'd be accustomed to it.

Comment: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6348.

Comment: Is Rabbi Fohrman the first to read it as "no one would cut you off"?

Comment: The Medrash Rabbah says the did not force you to drink Puska a cup so large you had to drink which made you insane

Comment: @Shalom, I don't know.